difference between 開発元 and 開発者
What's the difference between 開発元 and 開発者? Does one stand for a company and the other one for a person?

These two are straightforward:

開発者: "developer" as a person / occupation name
開発会社: "developer" as a development company

On the other hand, 開発元 can be either a person or a company. Essentially, it is a word used as a "role name" within a broader business scheme. It's not a term to describe the job of an individual or the type of a company, but it's "developer" in the sense of "who developed this". The kanji 元 means "source" or "origin", indicating nothing about whether the developer is an individual or a company.
For example, Nintendo is known as a famous ゲーム開発会社, but it is rarely referred to as ゲーム開発元. In Super Smash Bros. Ultimate, Nintendo itself acted as the publisher, while the actual development was carried out by Sora and Bandai Namco. In such situations, we refer to these two developers as 開発元, indicating their roles within this specific project. However, when someone asks, "What type of company is Bandai Namco?" irrespective of this game, you must say "Bandai Namco is a ゲーム開発会社". Saying "Bandai Namco is a ゲーム開発元" might confuse the listener or mistakenly suggest that the company only does contract development for other companies.

In game development, a 開発元 is almost always a company, but note that in small-scale projects, an individual or a small group of freelance developers can also serve as the 開発元.


Does one stand for a company and the other one for a person?

Basically yes.
開発者 strongly connotes a real person, and refers to a specific developer. On the other hand, 開発元 refers to an organization or a group of people who are responsible for a product.
